# Integrity constraint violation when deleting object in ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a many to many relationship between CATEGORY and PRODUCT in a very basic e-commerce java app.

Category has @ManyToMany relation with product. Therefore there is a table CATEGORY_PRODUCT with two colums CATEGORY_ID and PRODUCTS_ID

I want to delete all relations for certain product in that table, am i doing it right?

```
public void deleteProduct(long id){
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Product product = session.find(entityClass, id);

        String sql = "DELETE FROM PUBLIC.CATEGORY_PRODUCT WHERE PRODUCTS_ID = " + id;
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
        query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);

        session.delete(product);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

The plan is to delete the product but i have "integrity constraint violations" because of the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Before you call session.delete(product), you need to call query.executeUpdate().

You don't need the query.setResultTransformer() call. You should get rid of that line. The result of the executeUpdate() is an int that says how many records were deleted.

You asked this several months ago and I'm just now seeing it. I assume you aren't still waiting on an answer, but maybe this can help the next person.